# Map SwiftyJSON to array

Tags: swift, swifty-json

```
let json = JSON(response.result.value!)

let things = json.array.map { jsonThing in          
   Thing()                    
}!
```

`json.array` returns an array of one hundred `JSON`s. After the call to `map`, I end up with a single `Thing`.

Why don't I have a new array of `Thing`s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SwiftyJSON has two kinds of getters: optional and non-optional.

The non-optional getters have the "...Value" name syntax.

Optional:

```
json.array
```

Non-optional:

```
json.arrayValue
```

Be careful, though: if you're using the non-optional getters with a nil value it will crash. If the value can be nil it's better to use the optional getter and safely unwrap with `if let` (optional binding) or any other known technique: optional chaining, nil coalescing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Because `json.array`returns `[JSON]?`, not `[JSON]`

Thus you have called `.map` on a single instance of `Optional<[JSON]>` rather than an `Array<JSON>` as you were expecting.

You need to call:

`json.array?.map ...`

Comment: Great explanation but not quite as comprehensive as Eric D's. ;)